# How to prove that the n-dimensional sphere is an orientable?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I need a help  in how to prove that the n-dimensional sphere ia an orientable:
How we can prove this?

Comment: There’s nothing in your question to indicate that it is related to Mathematica, it looks purely like a math question to me. Are you sure you’re on the right site?

Comment: Show that there exists a volume form. This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284234/volume-form-on-n-1-sphere-sn-1

Comment: What is your definition of oriantable?

Answer (score 3):

Take a unit sphere $S_n$. Construct a vector field $\mathbf n=\mathbf x$ defined on $S_n$. Then you can easily show that this vector field is continuous, has unit length, and normal to $S_n$. So by definition you have defined orientation to your surface, and this the surface is orientable.