# Integral of a volume form and stokes theorem

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, stokes-theorem, manifolds-with-boundary, exterior-derivative

I currently have an expression of the following form:

$$\int_{\partial A} f(x) dH_{n-1}(x)$$

Where $A$ is an orientable Riemannian Manifold of dimension $n$, $H_{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure and $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^\infty$ function. I wish to use Generalized Stoke's theorem to convert the above into something of the form:

$$\int_{A} g(x) dM(x)$$

where $g$ is some function and $M$ is some function. I am still new to differential forms but from what I understand I can do something like the following:

---

By [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87930/hausdorff-measure-and-the-volume-form), I can replace the Hausdorff measure with the $n-1$ dimensional volume form, $\omega_{n-1}$ like so:

$$\int_{\partial A} f(x) dH_{n-1}(x)=\int_{\partial A} f(x) \omega_{n-1}(x)$$

I can then write out the product $f(x) \omega_{N-1}(x)$ as follows:

$$f(x)\omega_{N-1}(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}f(x)x_{j}dx_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge \hat{dx_{j}}\wedge\cdots \wedge dx_{n}$$

where $x_j$ is the $j^{th}$ component of $x$ and $\hat{dx_{j}}$ represents that $\hat{dx_{j}}$ is neglected from the wedge. (I got the above expression from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284234/volume-form-on-n-1-sphere-sn-1)).

If I differentiate this form I think I get the below:

$$d(f(x) \omega_{N-1}(x))= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}\frac{\partial [f(x)x_{j}]}{\partial x_i}dx_{i}\wedge dx_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge \hat{dx_{j}}\wedge\cdots \wedge dx_{n}$$

$$= \sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}\frac{\partial [f(x)x_{j}]}{\partial x_j}dx_{j}\wedge dx_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge \hat{dx_{j}}\wedge\cdots \wedge dx_{n}$$

$$= \sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}(-1)^{j-1}\frac{\partial [f(x)x_{j}]}{\partial x_j}dx_{1}\wedge\cdots \wedge dx_{n}$$

$$= \sum_{j=1}^{n}\bigg(f(x)\frac{\partial x_{j}}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_j}x_{j}\bigg) dx_{1}\wedge\cdots \wedge dx_{n}$$

$$= \bigg(nf(x)+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_j}x_{j}\bigg) dx_{1}\wedge\cdots \wedge dx_{n}$$
(assuming an $x_1,\cdots x_n$ are orthonormal).

$$= \bigg(nf(x)+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_j}x_{j}\bigg) dx$$

where $dx$ is shorthand for $dx_{1}\wedge\cdots \wedge dx_{n}$. By applying the generalized Stoke's theorem I then get;

$$\int_{\partial A} f(x) \omega_{N-1}(x)=\int_{A} d(f(x) \omega_{N-1}(x))$$
$$=\int_{A} \bigg(nf(x)+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_j}x_{j}\bigg) dx$$

So I have that $g(x)=\bigg(nf(x)+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_j}x_{j}\bigg)$ and $M(x)=x$.

---

My question is this; is this approach correct to get the integral over $A$ I originally set out to obtain? The placement of $n$ in the final integral seems odd to me...

There are a lot of concepts in the above text that are still very new to me, and I am not sure that I am applying them correctly. I am still struggling with the differentiation and am unsure if my final expression is correct.

Can anyone verify my working and help if I have done this wrong?

Comment: The coordinate expression you start with is specific to the $(n-1)$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and isn't relevant to the general case.

Comment: Ah I see... is there a general case I could use?

Comment: In oriented coordinates $x^1,\cdots,x^n$ the volume form has the form$$\omega=\sqrt{\det g}\ dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^n$$where $\det g$ denotes the determinant of the matrix representation of the metric in those coordinates.

Comment: Also, It's unclear to me what you're trying to do with the computation. Essentially you're trying to find an $(n-1)$-form $\mu$ on $A$ such that the restriction of $\mu$ to $\partial A$ is equal to $f\omega_{n-1}$ (which is an $(n-1)$ form on $\partial A$). You then have $\int_Ad\mu=\int_{\partial A}f\omega_{n-1}$ by Stokes' theorem.

Comment: I think $\mu$ would be an $n$-form? But yes, in essence, I want to replace an integral over $\partial A$ with an integral over $A$ using Generalized Stoke's theorem. If I have assumed $x^1,... x^n$ are orthonomal, would I be correct in thinking that $g$ is the identity and $\sqrt{\det g}=1$?

Comment: $\mu$ would need to be an $(n-1)$-form, so that $d\mu$ is an $n$-form which can be integrated over the $n$-manifold $A$. It's not generally possible to choose coordinates (even locally) such that the metric is the identity; it can only be done on flat manifolds.

Comment: Right I see. So in the case of say $n$-manifolds that are just n-dimensional subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the identity could be used but in curved spaces g could be anything?

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite what I have tried to do above using $\sqrt{\det g}$ in the place of $x_j$ then? Does anything simplify?

Comment: In either case, you won't be able to write down a concrete coordinate form without a concrete description of the manifold $A$ and a specific choice of coordinate chart(s). If you're willing to be a bit more abstract, you can construct such a $\mu$ using oriented charts adapted to the boundary and a partition of unity.

Comment: I see. How could I go about doing it the way you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there are many possible choices of $g$ and $M$. Here's a way to construct one with $g=1$ using a partition of unity. For convenience, I'll use $n$ for the dimension of $\partial A$.

It suffices to find an $n$-form $\mu$ on $A$ such that $\mu|_{\partial A}=f\omega_{\partial A}$, where $\omega_{\partial_A}$ is the Riemann volume form on $\partial A$. Then, by Stokes' theorem, we then have $\int_Ad\mu=\int_{\partial A}\mu|_{\partial A}=\int_{\partial A}f\omega_{\partial A}$.

Let $x_\alpha=(x_\alpha^0,\cdots,x_\alpha^n):U_\alpha\to\mathbb{H}^{n+1}$ be a collection of oriented boundary charts indexed by $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$ which covers $\partial A$, where
$$
\mathbb{H}^{n+1}=\{(x^0,\cdots,x^n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:x^0\ge 0\}
$$
is the half space. Note that $(x^1_\alpha,\cdots,x^n_\alpha):U_\alpha\cap\partial A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ are oriented charts on $\partial A$, which cover it. In these charts, $f\omega_{\partial A}$ has the following form:
$$
f\omega_{\partial A}=f\sqrt{\det g_{\partial A}}\ dx_\alpha^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_\alpha^n
$$
Here $g_{\partial A}$ denotes the matrix representation of the induced metric on $\partial A$. We can locally extend this form on each chart in the obvious way, defining forms $\mu_\alpha\in\Omega^n(U_\alpha)$ by
$$
\mu_\alpha(x_\alpha^0,\cdots,x_\alpha^n)=f(x_\alpha^1,\cdots,x_\alpha^n)\sqrt{\det g_{\partial A}(x_\alpha^1\cdots,x_\alpha^n)}\ dx_\alpha^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_\alpha^n
$$
Each of these is smooth, since $f$ and $g_{\partial A} $ depend smoothly on the last $n$ variables. Let $\{\psi_0,\psi_1,\psi_2\cdots\}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to the covering $\{A\setminus\partial A,U_1,U_2,\cdots\}$. We can define a global form $\mu$ by
$$
\mu=\sum_{\alpha=1}^\infty\psi_\alpha\mu_\alpha
$$
Which is well-defined and smooth on all of $A$, and satisfies $\mu|_{\partial A}=f\omega_{\partial A}$.

Comment: Ah right I see! Sorry it has taken me a little while to work through this and understand it! The only question I have is can you define a partition of unity for a non-finite set as you have done here for $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{N}$? I've never seen this done before - do you have any references for how I could construct such a partition of unity?

Comment: @JDoe2 Conversely I've never heard of partitions of unity only being defined on finite covers; They exist for any open cover of a manifold. Most any [introductory texts on manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46482/introductory-texts-on-manifolds) should cover this case (I know this to be the case for Tu and both Lees on that list). The idea is that you use the fact that manifolds are [paracompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space) to obtain a locally finite refinement, which is all you need.

Comment: Ah right I see - I'm currently working through Lees series but must not have seen that yet - thank you for the clarification and answer! You've really helped me here